# Is it safe to start a Play 2 plugin from another plugin?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm writing a Play module that includes several plugins (some of which are third-party), and I was wondering if it would be safe to have my core plugin start all the other plugins; something like this:

```scala
class CorePlugin(app: Application) extends Plugin {
   lazy val otherPlugin = OtherPlugin(app)
   lazy val thirdParty = ThirdPartyPlugin(app)

   override def onStart() {
     otherPlugin.onStart()
     thirdParty.onStart()
   }

   override def onStop() {
     thirdParty.onStop()
     otherPlugin.onStop()
   }
}
```

Would doing something like that make Play freak out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Play won't have any problems, but, the plugins may rely on actually being among the play plugins which could make them break, and also, being listed in conf/play.plugins could lead to two instances of the same plugin which would probably also give strange behaviour etc.

Comment: Hmmm... hadn't thought about the possibility of accidentally enabling a plugin twice. Sounds like it's not really worth the risk. Thanks.